# Skipping sunday in oracle days difference

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to query an sql to select days remaining but neglecting sundays, so far I have this

```
select to_date(due_date) - trunc(sysdate) 
from project 
where project_name = 'SUPPERHOUSE'
```

and how to ignore sunday occurences ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the past I used a query like this:

```
select TRUNC (sysdate) - TRUNC (due_date) -1 *  (to_char(sysdate, 'WW') - to_char(due_date, 'WW')) solution
  from project
where project_name = 'SUPPERHOUSE'
```

You can check this [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ba047b/1).

Comment: This solution fails if the timespan is more than one year!

Comment: you are right, I was able to remove a fixed number of sundays per year of difference (52), but the best solution would be a separate function that calculates the number of sunday for each year between due_date and sysdate. unfortunately this requires a bit of time to do it